# Using the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for C# is there a method to Hit Test for a polygon on the graphics layer?

Tags: c#, polygon, sdk, arcgis-runtime

I am very new to using ArcGIS runtime SDK for C#.
I have loaded a polygon from a shapefile.
I wish to query if a lat/long point is inside or outside the polygon?

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you talking about the [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/runtime-wpf/)?

Answer (score 2):

The Geometry Engine has a contains method:

```
static boolean  contains(Geometry geometry1, Geometry geometry2, SpatialReference spatialReference)
```

Just check if the point is in the polygon...